# Why does a CopyConstructible type also have to be MoveConstructible?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, c++20

As stated in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible), a requirement for a type **T** to be **CopyConstructible** is that it also be **MoveConstructible**.

The draft for the STL [CopyConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/CopyConstructible) concept contains:

> ```
> template <class T>
> concept CopyConstructible =
>    std::MoveConstructible<T> &&
>    std::Constructible<T, T&> && std::ConvertibleTo<T&, T> &&
>    std::Constructible<T, const T&> && std::ConvertibleTo<const T&, T> &&
>    std::Constructible<T, const T> && std::ConvertibleTo<const T, T>;
> ```

which supports the named requirement statement. Given the above definition, a type like:

```
struct HaveCopy {
   HaveCopy(const HaveCopy&)  = default;
   HaveCopy(HaveCopy&&)       = delete;
   HaveCopy& operator= (const HaveCopy&)  = default;
   HaveCopy& operator= (HaveCopy&&)       = delete;
};
```

fails the simple test:

```
static_assert(std::CopyConstructible<HaveCopy>);
```

whereas it passes the old:

```
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<HaveCopy>::value);
```

So, the question is **why**? What's the intention of the standards committee on that matter? HaveCopy is not move constructible but is pretty much copy constructible in my opinion and `std::is_copy_constructible<>` agrees with me.

The same behavior is also inherited by the [Copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/Copyable) concept, which is:

> ```
> template <class T>
> concept Copyable =
>    std::CopyConstructible<T> &&
>    std::Movable<T> &&
>    std::Assignable<T&, const T&>;
> ```

So the test:

```
static_assert(std::Copyable<HaveCopy>);
```

will fail also. This time the failure is doubled. Both `CopyConstrucible<>` and `Movable<>` disagree that HaveCopy is copyable.

The discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041787/are-all-copyconstructible-types-moveconstructible-types) is somehow similar but does not answer the **why**. Why do we need this behavior? Does this kind of check exclude valid copy constructible types or is HaveCopy not copy constructible at all? The last seems really weird to me if it is true.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Doesn't Jonathan Wakely's answer in the linked thread answer the why-part, too? "MoveConstructible doesn't require that anything gets moved, only that construction from rvalues is possible, and all CopyConstructible types can be constructed from rvalues (even if they might do a deep copy not a move)."

Comment: my understanding is that when something gets moved you are not supposed to care wether it actually got moved or copied, hence if something is `CopyConstructible` it automatically is `MoveConstructible`, you cannot tell the difference, and it isnt really an additional requirement

Comment: i do agree with lubr, and would flag this question as a duplicate, what part do you thing is not answered by the linked answer?

Comment: While its very possible that I don't understand it well... Wakely's answer says "We try to avoid  perverse types [and/so], ?we need the move constructor also because someone may use it to copy?". Why we do that by asking for MoveConstructible concept? And why while doing that we exclude HaveCopy from being CopyConstructible?

Comment: @ user463035818 My question is on the why part. I can not understand why by trying to avoid perverse types we ban types with deleted move constructor but with pretty valid copy constructor. Why we need this behavior? Does this kind of check excludes valid copy constructible types or HaveCopy is not copy constructible at all?

Comment: It's like asking "why do all numbers divisible by 4 have to be divisible by 2?". Any `T` that can be instantiated from a `const T &` can be instantiated from a `T &&`, because of the "implicit conversion" of `T &&` to `const T &`. "can be instantiated from a `T &&`" is how MoveConstructible *is defined*

Comment: @Caleth As OP showed with `HaveCopy`, that is not necessarily the case. It's true that the copy constructor would be a candidate - it's not true that the copy constructor is necessarily the _best_ candidate.

Comment: based on answers if its our intention to support all meaningful combinations of `T`, `const`, `&` and `&&`, shouldn't we use `||` in the definition of CopyConstructible? The answer mentions "it's also about enforcing semantic requirement", clearly `HaveCopy` is copy constructible. Isn't that semantically enough?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, `CopyConstructible` the concept is quite different than the type trait `std::is_copy_constructible`. You're focusing on the move constructor, but there are many other cases to consider as well. Do you think this type should be CopyConstructible?

```
struct A {
    A(A&) = delete;
    A(A const&);
};
```

How about this one?

```
struct B {
    explicit B(B const&);
};
```

The point is, there's an endless variety of combinations of constructors you can write. That doesn't mean that they're all meaningful or worth supporting. Having a type with a copy constructor but a deleted move constructor simply does not make sense.

Concepts isn't about just doing a syntactic check, it's also about enforcing semantic requirements to push for meaningful types - which end up being easier to code around. If you simply check `is_copy_constructible`, all you're allowing yourself to do is to *explicitly* construct your type from a const lvalue. Writing `T x = y;`, even if `y` is a `const T`, is already outside of that scope! That might be literally what copy constructible means, but it's a lot less meaningful than the broader "I can construct a `T` from a `T`" - which is a lot closer to really what we think of when we consider copying. That's what the concept `CopyConstructible` gives us.

As you go through the library, there are other concepts that require more (syntactically and semantically) than a direct translation of their name might suggest. [`EqualityComparableWith<T,U>`](http://eel.is/c++draft/concepts#concept.equalitycomparable) doesn't just check that I can write `t == u` but also `u == t`, `t != u`, and `u != t` as well. [`StrictTotallyOrdered`](http://eel.is/c++draft/#concept.stricttotallyordered) doesn't just check the ordering operators, it *also* checks `==`. Having a cohesive whole is important.

Comment: So its all about wording? If so consider my intuitive reaction to concept wording. First to quote from your (very good) answer for CopyConstructible: "I can construct a T from a T". Is this what Constructible is for? Second... would it be better for CopyConstructible to be "I can COPY a T from a T" ?

Comment: @hoo2: Requirements like this are more about the viability of expressions than the semantic effects (though they have them too). Consider `T t = some_t;` and `T t = func_returning_t();`. Does the user care exactly whether it is a "COPY" or not? Or do they just care that they have a `T` and are able to construct another `T` from it?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Of course the user cares. Consider a library with objects holding hardware resources. These objects are allowed to move but not to copy. The author of that library have to make a lot of checks and better wording could make his life easier. In my opinion every time we make assumptions like that we weaken the language. Isn't a precise tool, a better tool? And saying that I don't mean I have right on wording. I say that as part of the discussion.

Comment: @hoo2: Yes, the user cares whether the type is move *only*, and thus `T t = some_t;` doesn't compile. But why should a user desire `T t = func_returning_t();` to not compile? If you can create an instance from an lvalue, why can you not create one from an rvalue? A type which is copyable-but-not-moveable is a type that breaks the basic underlying concepts of these operations.

Comment: @hoo2 "allowed to move but not to copy" is a perfectly reasonable semantic, that has no shortage of important use-cases. "allowed to copy but not to move" is... literally a possible thing to write. Those aren't exactly on equal footing.

Comment: On a related note, per cppreference, many containers(eg. vector) state that `T must meet the requirements of CopyAssignable and CopyConstructible.` In C++17, std::vector with nonmovable objects is supported. Does this mean that in future versions or with specific compilers said support might drop as these containers are implemented using concepts?

Comment: @tangy That sentence says "(until C++11)" on it.